# 複数の Python コードをコマンドプロンプトから同時に起動したい

Tags: python, コマンドプロンプト

複数のPython コードを一度に同時に実行させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

コマンドプロンプトに `python script.1 script.2 script.3 ...` だと script.1 しか動きませんでした。script.1の処理が完了しないとだめなのでしょうか？

処理を同時に複数実行させる場合どのようにコマンドプロンプトに入力すればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`start python 1.py & start python 2.py`のように`start python ???.py`を`&`区切りで併記することで、複数のコマンドを一括実行できます。
このとき各コマンドごとにコマンドプロンプトのウインドウが開きます。

Answer (score 1):

もしコマンドプロンプトでなくてもよいのであれば，PowerShell 7.0 以上を使って `ForEach-Object -Parallel` で並列化できます。（参考：[PowerShell 7.0 の新機能](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7.1#parallel-execution-added-to-foreach-object)）

```
PS> ("a.py", "b.py") | ForEach-Object -Parallel { python3 $_ }
b
a
```

各スクリプトの内容は次のようなものです。

```
# a.py
import time
time.sleep(3)
print("a")

# b.py
print("b")
```